# Is Kigg MVC application DRY? Can we tweak the Repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, inversion-of-control, repository, kigg

I was recently taking a look at the Kazi Manzur Kigg MVC implementation (Kazi rocks) and noticed some code that seemed to defeat the DRY/SOC principle.  I'd love to have everyone's thoughts on a possible refactor to separate concerns.

Kigg implements both an `Add` and `Remove` method on each repository class ( **Note**: `BaseRepository` has virtual methods than can be overloaded by each concrete implementation.)

The implementations for the `Kigg.Repository.LinqToSql.CategoryRepository` and the `Kigg.Repository.LinqToSql.StoryRepository` both cascade deletes via their `Remove` methods in order to delete child entities.  ( **Note**:  Category has a parent relationship (one-to-many) to Story, so they share the same child relationships from Story down through the object graph) [see diagram](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/02/12/domain-model-developing-kigg-v2-0-part-1.aspx) .  The offending code is the way both repositories delete each others child entities:

**CategoryRepository**

```
namespace Kigg.Repository.LinqToSql.CategoryRepository{
    //using statements omitted
    public class CategoryRepository : BaseRepository<ICategory, Category>, ICategoryRepository
    {
    //code omitted

    public override void Remove(ICategory entity)
    {
        Check.Argument.IsNotNull(entity, "entity");

        Category category = (Category) entity;

        Database.DeleteAll(Database.StoryViewDataSource.Where(v => v.Story.CategoryId == category.Id));
        Database.DeleteAll(Database.CommentSubscribtionDataSource.Where(cs => cs.Story.CategoryId == category.Id));
        Database.DeleteAll(Database.CommentDataSource.Where(c => c.Story.CategoryId == category.Id));
        Database.DeleteAll(Database.VoteDataSource.Where(v => v.Story.CategoryId == category.Id));
        Database.DeleteAll(Database.MarkAsSpamDataSource.Where(sp => sp.Story.CategoryId == category.Id));
        Database.DeleteAll(Database.StoryTagDataSource.Where(st => st.Story.CategoryId == category.Id));
        Database.DeleteAll(Database.StoryDataSource.Where(s => s.CategoryId == category.Id));

        base.Remove(category);
    }
}
}
```

**StoryRepository**

```
namespace Kigg.Repository.LinqToSql
{

    //using statements omitted


    public class StoryRepository : BaseRepository<IStory, Story>, IStoryRepository
    {

    //code omitted


    public override void Remove(IStory entity)
    {
        Check.Argument.IsNotNull(entity, "entity");

        Story story = (Story) entity;

        Database.DeleteAll(Database.StoryViewDataSource.Where(sv => sv.StoryId == story.Id));
        Database.DeleteAll(Database.CommentSubscribtionDataSource.Where(cs => cs.StoryId == story.Id));
        Database.DeleteAll(Database.CommentDataSource.Where(c => c.StoryId == story.Id));
        Database.DeleteAll(Database.VoteDataSource.Where(v => v.StoryId == story.Id));
        Database.DeleteAll(Database.MarkAsSpamDataSource.Where(sp => sp.StoryId == story.Id));
        Database.DeleteAll(Database.StoryTagDataSource.Where(st => st.StoryId == story.Id));

        base.Remove(story);
    }
    }

}
```

Would I be correct in assuming that a better design would have the `CategoryRepository` calling the `Remove` method on the `StoryRepository`, thereby delegating the concern for the Story's child object removal to the `StoryRepository` where it belongs?  From a maintenance point-of-view any additions to the Story's children would require `DeleteAll` calls to be added to both the `CategoryRepository` and the `StoryRepository`.

What would be a better implementation?

Should the `CategoryRepository` be refactored to use the `StoryRepository` directly?:
**CategoryRepository (refactor)**

```
namespace Kigg.Repository.LinqToSql.CategoryRepository{
    //using statements omitted
    public class CategoryRepository : BaseRepository<ICategory, Category>, ICategoryRepository
    {
    //code omitted

    public override void Remove(ICategory entity)
    {
        Check.Argument.IsNotNull(entity, "entity");

        Category category = (Category) entity;

        // refactor - start
        StoryRepository _storyRepository = new StoryRepository( Database );
        category.Stories.ForEach( story => _storyRepository.Remove( story ) );
        // refactor - end

        base.Remove(category);
    }
}
}
```

This refactor would allow the `CategoryRepository` to reuse the removal logic in the `StoryRepository` and should also reuse the same LinqToSql `DataContext` that is referenced by the `Database` argument given to the `StoryRepository` constructor.  But when it comes to unit testing it starts to have an odor.

Would a better refactor include using IoC (Kigg uses Unity as its Ioc container) to inject the `PerWebRequest` scoped instance of `IStoryRepository` into the `CategoryRepository`'s constructor?

**CategoryRepository (refactor take 2)**

```
namespace Kigg.Repository.LinqToSql.CategoryRepository{
    //using statements omitted
    public class CategoryRepository : BaseRepository<ICategory, Category>, ICategoryRepository
    {


    private readonly IStoryRepository _storyRepository;

    public CategoryRepository(IDatabase database, IStoryRepository storyRepository) : base(database)
    {
        Check.Argument.IsNotNull(storyRepository, "storyRepository");
        _storyRepository = storyRepository;
    }

    public CategoryRepository(IDatabaseFactory factory, IStoryRepository storyRepository) : base(factory)
    {
        Check.Argument.IsNotNull(storyRepository, "storyRepository");
        _storyRepository = storyRepository;
    }

    //code omitted

    public override void Remove(ICategory entity)
    {
        {
        Check.Argument.IsNotNull(entity, "entity");

        Category category = (Category) entity;

        // refactor - start
        category.Stories.ForEach( story => _storyRepository.Remove( story ) );
        // refactor - end

        base.Remove(category);
    }
}
}
```

With this second refactor we can now inject an instance of `IStoryRepository` into `CategoryRepository` during unit testing and via Unity Ioc. Of course we would have to extend this refactor to each repository class so they could tend to their own children's responsibilites.

What are everyone's thoughts?

Comment: does this approach couple multiple Repository dependencies in a way that would be considered an anti-pattern

Answer (score 1):

Excuse my ignorance on L2S (i use NHibernate), but does it not handle cascades automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

JBland, LingToSql will handle cascades as defined in the database.  Although, SQL Server does not allow [multiple cascade paths](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321843).

The Kigg database doesn't have cascading Delete or Update rules defined, but they aren't needed if the repository implementation performs the necessary deletes.